# Loopback in Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, loopback

Is it possible to make a loopback Bluetooth connection in an Android phone so that one service can connect to another within the same phone (or even to itself)?

The idea is to use it so I can test a multi-player game that uses Bluetooth to communicate between players.

Comment: Get yourself an Android-X86 distro and usb bluetooth dongle that will be supported by it. One can use VirtualBOX for painless installation (with usb access being enabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible for bluetooth services to connect to itself or other services on the same phone.

Comment: Bluetooth spec clearly describes "loopback mode " ability - same as ANY other I/O device.

Answer (score 0):

You can for testing purposes according to the Bluetooth Spec.

[Bluetooth5.3 Specs](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=521059)

Link to spec pdf as of posting date:

https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=521059

Page 798