# Android: Possible to connect bluetooth to self?

Tags: android, bluetooth, simulate

At the beginning of this year, I tried to implement an android-app which could stream ALL system-audio to a remote system.

This was not easy because (at that time) there was no way to get all system-audio.
So I developed a kernel-module which hijacked the audio.

But it was a bit buggy and hard to release.

So I stopped work on it.

But now, some months later I wonder if it is possible to:

> Connect via bluetooth to myself (= simulate bluetooth), because then I
>   can forward system-audio to it via API and then fetch it on the other
>   side.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. For a couple of reasons there is no loopback device for Bluetooth (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497723/loopback-in-android-bluetooth) also), which you would basically want to use.

You might try looking into using PulseAudio as a replacement for Android's AudioFlinger, as Pulse offers a loopback module for Linux at least.