# Can an Android app discover a local BLE GATT server?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

If Android app A sets up a BLE GATT server, can Android app B (on the same device) discover and connect to that GATT server as a client?

Answer (score 0):

No this shouldn't be possible because Bluetooth doesn't allow a device to connect to itself. I can't find in the spec where it specifically states this, but I have tried to do this using different Bluetooth stacks in the past and I wasn't able to.

Some information is provided here:-

[Loopback in Android Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497723/loopback-in-android-bluetooth)